# How to use trained keras model?

Tags: python, keras, image-classification

I want to use trained model from https://www.kaggle.com/janeresh/imageprocess. I copied the notebook and tested it works perfectly. But if I download model.h5 and use it in Google Colab to predict masked or non masked it always return 0

I use this code to predict:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import cv2

model = load_model('model.h5',compile=True)
model.summary()

img = cv2.imread('masked_image.png')
img = cv2.resize(img,(75,75))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,75,75,3])

prediction = model.predict_classes(img)
prediction
```

and the return is

```
array([[0]], dtype=int32)
```

Thanks

Comment: don't compile it. and also use model.predict() . what is your output?

Comment: I tried and the output is `array([[0.]], dtype=float32)` for masked and non masked face

Comment: Maybe its something about data preprocessing. Did you correctly scale and transform your image?